# Image in the card appears very poorly because of styles (Bootstrap 4)

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, bootstrap-4

If you upload an image which has higher height and less width then it shows very poorly in the card (user cards). Here are the HTML and css parts. We are using Angular with it:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container-fluid" >
  <div class="row people-row">
    <div class="col-12 row">
      <div class="m1-* col-md-3 text-center" *ngFor="let user of filteredUsers | filter: searchByKeyword: 'name' | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 12, currentPage: p }">
        <div class="card card-person">
          <a  (click)="ViewUser(user)">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dfg5p1pww/image/upload/v{{user.picVersion}}/{{user.picId}}"
            alt="Card image" style="width:100%">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h4 class="card-title"> {{user.firstName}} {{user.lastName}}</h4>
              <p class="card-text">{{user.age}}</p>
              <p class="card-text">{{user.country}},{{user.city}}</p>
              <p class="material-icons" *ngIf="CheckIfOnline(user.username)">online</p>
              <a class="btn button-image closeButton btn-message" [routerLink]="['/chat', user.username]">Message</a>
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.card-img-top {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 200px;
    width: auto
}

.card-person {
  margin: 50px auto;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 0;
  border: 0;
  box-shadow: 1em 1em 2em rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}

.card-text {
 margin-bottom:0.2rem
}

.btn-match,
.btn-message {
  color:#ffffff;
  background: #FF512F;  /* fallback for old browsers */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #FF512F, #DD2476);  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #FF512F, #DD2476); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
transition: all .4s;
margin:5px;
border-radius:40px
}

.button-image:before {
  content: "";
  width: 23px;
  height: 23px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-size: 100%;
  vertical-align: text-top;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-position : center center;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

.btn-match.closeButton:before{
   background-image : url('../../../assets/images/heart-white.png');
}

.btn-message.closeButton:before{
  background-image : url('../../../assets/images/chat-white.png');

}

a.fill {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  }
```

What can cause such an issue and how can this problem be fixed in Bootstrap 4 so all type of images can be look normal?

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle for this?

Comment: You must avoid one solutions fits all. That is why in most sites, developers request the users to upload images with the given target sizes in px e.g. your image must not be more that  "height: 200px and width: 300px"... this is just an example. Because unfortunately by the nature of pixes, there is not way to treat a good sized photo to something oversized with css that easily.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is caused by the `background-size` CSS property. When set to `100%` the browser is trying to stretch the background image to fill the container in both directions.

**The background-size property takes several "keyword" inputs as well as percentage or pixel sizes.**

`background-size:cover` will make the smallest size fill the container with the remaining image "overflow" hidden.

`background-size:contain` will make the largest part of the image fill the container with a "letterbox" effect for any excess.

Then you can use `background-position` to define where that excess content get's cut or what part of the container is exposed.

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
}
img {
  width: 250px;
}

hr {
  margin: 20px 0;
}

div {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #dadada;
  background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1556229040-2a7bc8a00a3e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9);
  background-color: blue;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

span {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.cover {
  background-size: cover;
}

.contain {
  background-size: contain;
}

.pos {
  background-position: top left;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1556229040-2a7bc8a00a3e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9" />
<p>Image from Unsplash</p>

<hr />

<div class="cover">
  <span>background-size:cover</span>
</div>

<div class="contain">
  <span>background-size:contain</span>
</div>

<div class="cover pos">
  <span>Cover + background-position: left top</span>
</div>

<div class="contain pos">
  <span>Contain + background-position: left top</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if i'm right you are using `.card-img-top`
    so add the class `.card-person.card-img-top`